# Como converter String que contenha aspas em String mesmo, utilizando o replaceAll?

Tags: java

Eu tenho uma String como no exemplo abaixo

```
String a = "Meu pai é um Grande "baio" de fada";
```

eu quero fazer isso virar uma String assim

```
String a = "Meu pai é um Grande \"baio\" de fada";
```

como faço isso utilizando o replaceAll?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### replaceAll nas aspas

Seria algo como:

```
String a = "Meu pai é um Grande "baio" de fada";
a = a.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
```

Neste caso irá trocar qualquer aspas encontrada, independente se ser `"test` ou `"test"`.

### replaceAll entre as aspas

Mas a sua questão me parece que é mais com RegEx, o uso acredito que seja este:

```
String a = "Meu pai é um Grande "baio" de fada";
a = a.replaceAll("\"([^\"]+)\"", "\"$1\"");
```

Neste caso irá procurar todos que estiverem dentro das aspas como por exemplo `"?asd?asd/A/sd;;lasd"`

### replaceAll entre as aspas que contenham texto

No caso pode ser algo com com textos:

```
String a = "Meu pai é um Grande "baio" de fada";
a = a.replaceAll("\"([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)\"", "\"$1\"");
```

Neste caso irá procurar todos que estiverem dentro das aspas como por exemplo `"a e 0 9"`

Comment: Obrigado, respondeu minha dúvida